# Java Двоичный поиск

Tags: java

Задание: Создать массив случайных чисел, отсортировать его по убыванию, а затем провести двоичный поиск числа в данном массиве. Число вводит пользователь с клавиатуры.

Проблема где-то в двоичном поиске, прошу помочь и объяснить ошибку.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();
    int arr[] = new int[20];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {   //Заполнение массива
        arr[i] = rand.nextInt(50);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = arr.length - 2; j >= i; j--) {     //Cортировка по убыванию
            if (arr[j] < arr[j + 1]) {
                int temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {  //Вывод отсортированого массива
        System.out.print(arr[j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Введите число для поиска");
    int search = s.nextInt();        
    int nX = -1;
    int L = 0;
    int R = arr.length - 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        while (L <= R) {
            int k = (L + R) / 2;
            if (k == search) {
                nX = k;
                break;
            }
            else if (k < search) {
                R = k - 1;
            }
            else if (k > search) {
                L = k + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    if (nX == -1) {
        System.out.println("Искомого числа нет в массиве");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Искомое число было найдено и равно " + nX);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: возьмите карандаш и лист бумаги. Придумайте пример данных - не слишком простой (чтобы весь код исполнялся), но и не слишком сложный (чтобы можно было его сделать вручную). Пройдите по вашему коду шаг за шагом, записывая значения пременных. Очень скоро Вы сами обнаружите ошибку.

Comment: Что-то я не припомню чтобы в двоичном поиске был цикл `for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++)`, автоматически увеличивающий сложность алгоритма до `O(n)` (не говоря уж про `while` внутри `for`). Откуда взялся `for`?

Comment: Regent, это уже были танцы с бубном. Изначально for не было.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибок куча

1. Зачем нужен этот цикл?

   ```
   for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
   ```
2. Из этого

   ```
   int k = (L + R) / 2;
   if (k == search) {
   ```

`k` - индекс текущего проверяемого числа. И сравнивается с самим числом. Бред.

3.

```
break
```

Вышли из `while` цикла `for` продолжает крутиться

Итого, должно быть, что-то типа такого

```
int nX = -1;
int L = 0;
int R = arr.length - 1;
while (L <= R) {
    int k = (L + R) / 2;
    if (arr[k] == search) {
        nX = arr[k];
        break;
    }
    else if (arr[k] < search) {
        R = k - 1;
    }
    else if (arr[k] > search) {
        L = k + 1;
    }
}

if (nX == -1) {
    System.out.println("Искомого числа нет в массиве");
} else {
    System.out.println("Искомое число было найдено и равно " + nX);
}
```

Адекватность проверки `if (nX == -1)` оставляю на Вашей совести. Я бы не был бы так уверен, что в массиве не встретится `-1`

Эта строка

```
System.out.println("Искомое число было найдено и равно " + nX);
```

легко заменяется на такую

```
System.out.println("Искомое число было найдено и равно " + search);
```

Может логичнее выводить **индекс** найденного числа?

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли!
На счет ошибок:
1-я отмеченная Вами ошибка, была добавлена уже после, как крайность и я заранее понимал что так нельзя. Так что - полностью моя ошибка, хоть и осознанная.
2-я отмеченная Вами ошибка, я теперь понял свой основной косяк. Изначально у меня был такой же код, как предоставили Вы, единственное были различия в наименовании переменных, но суть та же. Проблема была в том, что я индекс текущего числа обозвал по одному, а в массиве называл по другому и не заметил этого, а ошибку не понимал. 
В общем, спасибо Вам еще раз! Добра Вам и удачи!