# Бинарный(двоичный) поиск

Tags: java

Пишу домашку, нужно написать поиск, который будет выбирать границы и искать в той части массива, что может идти не так в моём коде?

```
package javaguru;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class hw {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] nums = {3, 7, 19, 49, 54, 98, 105, 207, 209, 382};


    int i = 0, poisk = 7;


    int n = nums.length;
    int left = 0, right = nums.length, mid;

    mid = (left + right)/2;

}

    while(nums[mid]!= poisk){
            if (nums[mid] == poisk) {
                System.out.println("Chislo najdenno"+poisk);
                break;
            } else if (nums[mid] < poisk) {
                right = mid+1;
            } else if (nums[mid] > poisk) {
                left = mid - 1;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

---

Подправлил код, вот что из этого вышло, но всё равно результат не тот

package javaguru;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class hw {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] nums = {3, 7, 19, 49, 54, 98, 105, 207, 209, 382};


    int i = 0, poisk = 207;


    int n = nums.length;
    int left = 0, right = nums.length - 1, mid;





    while(left <= right){

        mid = (left + right)/2;

        if (nums[mid] == poisk) {
                System.out.println("Chislo najdenno"+poisk);
                break;
            } else if (nums[mid] < poisk) {
                right = mid-1;
            System.out.println(nums[mid]);
            } else if (nums[mid] > poisk) {
                left = mid + 1;
            System.out.println(nums[mid]);
        }
       }

}
```

}

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Java Двоичный поиск](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/727520/java-%d0%94%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba)

Comment: Накосячил с условиями в `else if `, смотри код в моём ответе

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В условии `while` сравнивай не значение, а индексы `left, right`

Задание правой границы `right = nums.length` в данном случае неправильно, уменьши её на 1.

В последнем исправлении ты напутал с половинками. Неужели этого по выводу не видно? Вот рабочий код:

```
public class HelloWorld
{
  // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int[] nums = {3, 7, 19, 49, 54, 98, 105, 207, 209, 382};


    int i = 0, poisk = 49;

    int n = nums.length;
    int left = 0, right = nums.length - 1, mid;

    System.out.println("Ischem " + poisk);

    while(left <= right){

        mid = (left + right)/2;

        if (nums[mid] == poisk) {
                System.out.println("Chislo najdeno "+poisk);
                break;
            } else if (nums[mid] > poisk) {
                right = mid-1;
            System.out.println(nums[mid]);
            } else if (nums[mid] < poisk) {
                left = mid + 1;
            System.out.println(nums[mid]);
        }
    }


  }
}
```